# Show that if $\dim V =n$ and $T$ is nilpotent, then $T^n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that if $\dim V =n$ and $T$ is nilpotent, then $T^n = 0$.

Is there a way to prove this without the Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Comment: Yes. Use the Jordan normal form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there is an $x \ne 0$ such that $T^{n+1}x=0$ but $T^nx\neq 0$. Then you can show that $\{ x,Tx,\cdots,T^{n}x \}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, which contradicts the assumption that $\dim{V}=n$.

Comment: +1 Cute ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is nilpotent, any nonzero subspace $W\subset V$ with $T(W) \subset W$ has $T(W) < W$; otherwise, we'd have $W = T^m W = 0$ for sufficiently large $m$. Thus $V > T(V) > T^2(V) > \cdots > T^{m-1}(V) > T^m(V) = 0$ for some $m$, from which the result immediately follows.